# Node.js/Express routing with get params

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I have get route like this:

```js
app.get('/documents/format/type', function (req, res) {
   var format = req.params.format,
       type = req.params.type;
});
```

So if I make request like

```
http://localhost:3000/documents/json/mini
```

in my format and type variables will be 'json' and 'mini' respectively, but if I make request like

```
http://localhost:3000/documents/mini/json
```

not. So my question is: how can I get the same variables in different order?

Comment: You don't `documents/mini/json` is `format == mini` and `type == json`. URL's are not unordered bags of parameters

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Your route isn't ok, it should be like this (with ':')

```
app.get('/documents/:format/:type', function (req, res) {
   var format = req.params.format,
       type = req.params.type;
});
```

Also you cannot interchange parameter order unfortunately.
For more information on `req.params` (and `req.query`) check out the api reference [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params).

Comment: //var sanitizer = require('sanitizer');
    var format = sanitizer.escape(req.params. format);  You really should sanitize the result. Or else your website has a HUGE vulnerability

Answer (score 58):

For Query parameters like `example.com/test?format=json&type=mini` format, then you can easily receive it via `req.query.<param>`

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  var format = req.query.format,
      type = req.query.type;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is also useful for me!

Comment: This made it so much easier to deal with a parameter that is a URL itself.

Comment: +1 This answers the question in the title, which I came here to find (the actual question has nothing to do with get params).