# How to acess axios params in nodejs get request

Tags: node.js, api, mongoose, axios

I am sending a get request to API with axios , but unable to acess the passed parametrs in that request.

Here is my code:
API request

```
 axios.get('http://localhost:4000/students',{
          params: {
            category:"indoor"
          }
        })
```

Request handling

```
router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.category);
  studentSchema.find({category:req.params.category},(error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
})
```

Routing is working properly when there is no parameters given.

console.log(req.params.category); is giving output as undefined.

Hope you got the Problem...

Comment: What about the route? Shouldn't it be "/students" instead of "/"?

Comment: @Wasbeer Routes are working fine.. I have already  included ''/students" route in server.js file

Comment: Could you share your code? Either .zip or Github repo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js/Express routing with get params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506658/node-js-express-routing-with-get-params)

Comment: Please read about ExpressJS
Params: http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.params
Body: http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.body
Mongoose Query: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html
Axios Params: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501185/how-to-post-query-parameters-with-axios

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do has got nothing to do with Axios,
To get query parameters, in the server side of your code, you need to use the property `query` of the request, like this:

```
let category = req.query["category"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`params` in Axios are URL parameters that become a [querystring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

`params` in Express' request object are route parameters. For example: When I define a URL such as `/students/:id` then `req.params` for `GET /students/value` will be `{id: "value"}`.

What you are looking for in Express handler is `req.query` [[docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)].